# How to set signature for python callables manually

Tags: python, python-3.6, signature, pybind11, python-jedi

I want to offer a code completion for my pybind11 modules using [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/). Jedi evaluates the `__signature__` of callables for its completion. For more information see: [Jedi struggles with pybind11 modules](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1388). But pybind11 is currently not able to generate them: [Set the text_signature attribute of callables](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/945)

Is there a way to manually set the `__signature__` of callables (especially functions) using the python interpreter after the pybind11 module has been loaded? Something like this:

`pyModule.myFunc.__signature__ = *Do some magic here*`

Are there maybe some tools that can generate the signature of python callables? There are lot of packages for creating functions dynamically at runtime whcich also create the signature. But this is not my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this with Jedi because it looks like a lot of work to reliable set up and reproduce, but maybe the following will work already.

The canonical way to inspect a callable's signature is the aptly named [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) function. It relies on the magic `__annotations__` attribute, which can be modified at runtime:

```py
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> def foo(bar):
...     return True
... 
>>> signature(foo)
<Signature (bar)>  # empty signature
>>> import typing
>>> foo.__annotations__ = {'bar': typing.Union[bool, None], 'return': bool}
>>> signature(foo)
<Signature (bar: Union[bool, NoneType]) -> bool>   # now contains the info we added
```

Since `__signature__` is not a standard field, it might be generated by Jedi, their issue description in [the ticket you linked](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1388) also implies that they'd prefer to leverage `inspect.signature` directly.

Comment: I tested it with Jedi and it works for the return types of pybind11 functions, but not for their parameters. If I inspect the pybind11 function signature after setting the annotations I get the expected Signature object. But it seems that Jedi does not get it. Maybe this appproach is not a good idea for solving my completion problems anyway. If I have to add the annotations manually I think it is much better to generate stub files (like discussed in the Jedi Issue). But thank you very much for the input that led me to the conclusion.

Comment: No problem, I'd agree that stub files sound like a better solution. Good luck =)